# How does jBASE figure out where a file is located?

Tags: jbase

I am working with customer using jBASE and I checked the MD item to determine where the file existed and there was no MD item for the file. How does jBASE determine where the file is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jBASE uses the locations as defined in the `JEDIFILEPATH` environment variable to find your files:

https://docs.zumasys.com/jbase/environment-variables/jedifilepath/

But anything defined in the MD/VOC takes precedence.

Answer (score 0):

It looks for the item (I suppose you mean a jBASE hashed file) either in VOC/MD (defined in JEDIFILENAME_MD environment variable) or HOME path or current working directory path.
Perhaps your MD or VOC (Vocabulary) is pointing somewhere else than where you expect it to be - check the JEDIFILENAME_MD variable.